# In the saml2 request missing parameters SigAlg and Signature

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Good day,

We used ITfoxtec library version 1.2.2. This solution worked correctly.

We are now integrating the version 4.0.5 library. We need to use SHA-256 encoding. We used the 4.0.5 library from Nugets. According to the implementation example https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.

We changed the `AccountController`, added `App_Start \ IdentityConfig.cs` and added the `IdentityConfig.RegisterIdentity()` call in `Global.asax`.

Issue:
The SigAlg and Signature parameters are missing in the provider request.

[1.2.2 version library ITfoxtec, SAML tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbXVE.png)

[4.0.5 version library ITfoxtec, SAML tracker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6slA1.png)

**We set parameters:**

- `"Saml2:IdPMetadata" = "/App_Data/metadata.xml"`
- `"Saml2:Issuer" value = "http://xxx"`
- `"Saml2:SignatureAlgorithm" = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"`
- `"Saml2:SingleSignOnDestination" = "https://yyy/oamfed/idp/samlv20"`
- `"Saml2:SingleLogoutDestination" = "https://yyy/oamfed/idp/samlv20"`
- `"Saml2:SigningCertificateFingerPrint" = "5d223463130bd1e290f1ae8dc064d1c48ab517c2"`
- `"Saml2:CertificateValidationMode" = "None"`
- `"Saml2:RevocationMode" = "NoCheck"`

The parameter `"Saml2:SigningCertificateFingerPrint"` is a custom parameter, we load the certificate from the local storage:

```
Saml2Configuration.SigningCertificate = CertificateUtil.Load (StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get ("Saml2: SigningCertificateFingerPrint"));
```

Question:
Why are the SigAlg and Signature parameters missing in the request? Bad configuration? Bad implementation?

Please help
Well thank you
DM

Comment: out of interestt ...does the IdP meta data have "WantAuthnRequestsSigned=true" set?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. IDP metadata is set to "WantAuthnRequestsSigned = true". IDP metadata is read by the configuration, the WantAuthnRequestsSigned property is not read directly in this configuration.

Metadata:
`<md:IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">`

Read configuration:
`Saml2Configuration.SignatureValidationCertificates.AddRange(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SigningCertificates);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAML 2.0 do not require Authn Requests to be signed by default (Logout Requests are required to be signed through). Therefore, the [ITfoxtec Identity Saml2](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2) package do not include the SigAlg and Signature parameters by default in the request.

To sign Authn Requests set the `Saml2Configuration.SignAuthnRequest = true` in code or in configuration `"Saml2:SignAuthnRequest" = "true"`.

**Edited - read from metadata**

The `Saml2Configuration.SignAuthnRequest` can be set from the IDP metadata `WantAuthnRequestsSigned`.

.NET Framework sample code:

```
if(entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.WantAuthnRequestsSigned.HasValue) {
    Saml2Configuration.SignAuthnRequest = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.WantAuthnRequestsSigned.Value; 
}
```

.NET Framework sample [IdentityConfig.cs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebApp/App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs#L47)

.NET Core sample [Startup.cs](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L49)

Comment: If the IDP meta data has set `WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true"` and the SAML lib reads the meta data but ignores this, I would consider this as a bug in the SAML SP implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I did not notice the commented part of 'Saml2Configuration.SignAuthnRequest = true' in IdentityConfig.cs

Comment: It is a good idea to show how to read the WantAuthnRequestsSigned from metadata, thanks. I have added sample code and edited the answer.